# Why does my modal window load blank?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, simplemodal, userscripts

I'm *brand* new to javascript, and not surprised to be having an issue. Here's my userscript:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Open Modal-External Page-Iframe
// @version    0.1
// @match      http://barackobamaisyournewbicycle.com/
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// @require https://simplemodal.googlecode.com/files/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.4.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('body').append('<input type="button" value="test-modal-button" id="CP">');
  $("#CP").css("position", "fixed").css("top", 25).css("left", 0);
  $('#CP').click(function(){ 
      alert('testmodal');
      var src = "http://365.ericmmartin.com/";
      $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
          closeHTML:"",
          containerCss:{
              backgroundColor:"#fff", 
          borderColor:"#fff", 
          height:450, 
          padding:0, 
          width:830
          },
          overlayClose:true
      });
   });
});
```

---

### the issue

When I navigate to http://barackobamaisyournewbicycle.com, I see my button `[test-modal-button]` on the top left and when I click, the modal window appears, but http://365.ericmartin.com/ does not load in that modal window, and the modal window remains blank. Just now I put an `alert('testmodal');` statement in between, so that I know I am reaching that code when the button is clicked, but that's just for debugging purposes.

I pulled this example straight from

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

at

"// Display an external page using an iframe"; about 3/4 of the way down the page.

---

EDIT:

I changed the @match website for this question to the simplest webpage I could find, but then *actually* tried it on barackobamaisyournewbicycle.com and it started working. Must have something to do with the other site I was testing it out on? Although that doesn't make much sense to me. Since I've already put some effort into the question, are there any suggestions to improve my implementation?

Comment: What have you found in the documentation of simplemodal.googlecode.com

Comment: Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/QewEg/